# How do I fix the Symfony Component\Runtime\ResolverInterface error?

Tags: php, symfony

At the moment I'm just studying the Symfony framework, I've been working on controllers. And suddenly I see this error.

I cleaned the cache, but nothing helped, this error came out in the console.

The error itself looks like this:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Interface "Symfony\Component\Runtime\ResolverInterface" not found in /var/www/u1660023/data/www/site.ru/vendor/symfony/runtime/Resolver/ClosureResolver.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/u1660023/data/www/site.ru/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include() #1 /var/www/u1660023/data/www/site.ru/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/u16600...') #2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\Compone...') #3 /var/www/u1660023/data/www/lift-invest.ru/vendor/symfony/runtime/GenericRuntime.php(20): class_exists('Symfony\Compone...') #4 /var/www/u1660023/data/www/site.ru/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('/var/www/u16600...') #5 /var/www/u1660023/data/www/site.ru/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/u16600...') #6 /var/www/u1660023/data/www/site.ru/vendor/symfony/runtime/SymfonyRuntime.php(67): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\Compone...') #7 /var/www/u1660023/data/www/site.ru/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('/var/www/u16600...') #8 /var/www/u1660023/data/www/site.ru/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/u16600...') #9 /var/www/u1660023/data/www/site.ru/vendor/autoload_runtime.php(16): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\Compone...') #10 /var/www/u1660023/data/www/site.ru/public/index.php(5): require_once('/var/www/u16600...') #11 {main} thrown in **/var/www/u1660023/data/www/site.ru/vendor/symfony/runtime/Resolver/ClosureResolver.php** on line **19**

Comment: I suppose you could verify the interface file is still there but I am sure it is.  You could try a `composer dump-autoload` just in case the autoloader got messed up somehow.  Were you `studying` either `bin/console` or `public/index.php`?  Those are the only two files that really use the runtime out of the box except maybe the testing stuff.  Might need just a bit more info.

Comment: I didn't find anything easier than just reinstalling the framework.